# How to make a DIV always at the bottom of the page when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to make a DIV always at the bottom of the page when scrolled. But this is not working and goes on increasing the Page height.

```
var LSscrollingDiv = $("#LightSwitchMenuIt");
$(window).scroll(function(){
  LSscrollingDiv
      .stop()
      .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) + "px"}, "slow" );            
});
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: you can mix it with a jquery solution if you use the .scroll() function and using the css solutions already posted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not use straight CSS?

```
div.foo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;  
}
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/85Psw/)

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/CSS/position

Comment: beat me to it :P i was going to suggest a pure CSS solution

Answer (score 7):

This might be a simple CSS issue ... you can place a DIV to a fixed position at the bottom of the viewport and it will always be there when scrolling, without any Javascript

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use css

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

to avoid having to do this in javascript if you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8BGJ/ is a simple demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

It may help to have width set as inherit too.

```
#div {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this rules:

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You can also use this technique in any parent block element.